# How To Tell if jQuery is Used by a Site

Tags: jquery

I maintain a web site that someone else wrote who hasn't been with us for years. We've had a security review and one of the issues is that jQuery is significantly out of date. I don't personally have experience with jQuery, and I'm having difficult telling if jQuery is even used by the site, or if it was something the developer threw in just in case. I would expect that there are certain artifacts in the code if it's used.

I've taken the jQuery references out of packages.config and did a small smoke test on some of the site functionality without any ill effects, but I don't even know enough to know if that is a valid test.

If jQuery is in use, what should I look for? And would it be in the C# code or the HTML?

Comment: check for $ symbols in javascript code

Comment: If you type `jQuery` into your JS console and jQuery is enabled, it should show you a result like `ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}` - otherwise you'll get a reference error.

Comment: Do you mean symbols like this? $("#Go").click()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a jquery-{version}.js file that you need to be looking for. Further, you can scan through html and js files looking for "$()" type jquery selectors to verify jquery usage.

Comment: Based on this, it appears that jQuery is used for the sole purpose of converting a "Return" in an edit field into a click on a related button. And thank you...this is exactly the kind of clue I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this web to check it: https://www.wappalyzer.com/

It tells you what frameworks is the site using and you can look for jQuery and many others.

Hope it helps!